# Should I be creating a separate app in my Apple Dev account for testing the development version of my production app?

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

I have an app in the app store that I built with Phonegap Build.

I'm working on the new version, and have realised that in order to debug it, it needs to be created with a dev cert.

Does this mean I need to set up a totally new app in my Apple Dev and iTunesConnect accounts that I upload my development version to in Testflight, and then create the production version to upload to the production app in iTunesConnect, or do I just have one app, and apply a development cert to the testflight updates that I'm uploading to it while testing?

I'm worried that applying a dev cert to the app in my Apple Dev account will turn the production app that's in the app store into a dev app.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: How did you debug the version that is already in the AppStore then? Normally you have two certificates. A "Developer" and a "Distribution" certificate. You sign the Debug-artifact with the Developer one so you can debug, and the Release-artifact with the Distribution-cert.

Comment: Hi TMob. I can't remember how I originally debugged - it was that long ago. So should I have two app ids set up eg com.mysite.devappname and com.mysite.productionappname - is that the done thing, or do you have one app id eg com.mysite.justthisappname and sign it with a dev cert when testing but then a production cert when releasing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: No. The app-ID is the same. Its the same app afterall. You sign it differently for the Debug and Release scheme as you said. This is indirectly defined by what provisioning profile you choose. You have to have two provisioning profiles, one assigned for each certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two certificates. A 'Development' and a 'Distribution'. You can create those via [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) under "Development" and "Production".

[image]

For each certificate you create a provisioning profile also on the website. Those you can then download through XCode.

In your project-file you then select the provisioning profile for the "Development"-certificate under "Signing(Debug)" and the one for the "Distribution" under "Signing(Release)"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can give Test Flight with Production certificate.No need to create new app.In the same app we can give test flight.It wont affect to distribution app. Just go through test flight option in apple account.